# is it possible to define index in create table statement itself in db2?

Tags: sql, db2, create-table

Can I create an index on a CREATE TABLE statement?
I.e. can I define indexes for a table when I create the table? I mean create the index on the create statement SQL command

Comment: You'll have implicit indexes for primary key or unique constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique index by adding a `UNIQUE` constraint during the table creation; the engine will implement the constraint using a unique index. Mind that in DB2 the columns need to be `NOT NULL` to participate in a `UNIQUE` constraint.

For example:

```
create table t (
  a int,
  b varchar(10) not null,
  c date not null,
  constraint uq1 unique (b, c)
);
```

The constraint creates an index that includes the columns `b` and `c`.